# Awk array is printing elements in unexpected order

Tags: awk

I am using awk to capture timestamp from a dataset, and print out a value (memory) associated with that timestamp.

The following awk code works well to achieve this.

```
awk '
/show memory compare start/     {getline
                                 start_time = $0;
                                }
/show memory compare end/       {getline
                                 end_time = $0;
                                }
/mibd_interface/{
        print start_time, $3, "\n" end_time, $4
}' snmpoutput.txt

Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB 8670334
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB 8484152
Thu Sep 19 14:43:07.946 WIB 8369050
Thu Sep 19 14:45:27.916 WIB 8514825
Thu Sep 19 14:46:28.464 WIB 8446906
Thu Sep 19 14:50:10.422 WIB 8264885
Thu Sep 19 14:50:44.374 WIB 8264884
Thu Sep 19 14:55:05.760 WIB 8264960
```

After putting this data into an array and printing it, the elements appear out of order.

I have entered the order of appearance in the right most column, when comparing this output with the desired output above.

```
awk '
/show memory compare start/     {getline
                                 start_time = $0;
                                }
/show memory compare end/       {getline
                                 end_time = $0;
                                }

/mibd_interface/{mem_stats[start_time]=$3; mem_stats[end_time]=$4} END {for (time in mem_stats) {printf "%s => %s\n",time,mem_stats[time]}}' snmpoutput.txt

Thu Sep 19 14:55:05.760 WIB => 8264960  8
Thu Sep 19 14:45:27.916 WIB => 8514825  4 
Thu Sep 19 14:43:07.946 WIB => 8369050  3
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB => 8484152  2 
Thu Sep 19 14:50:44.374 WIB => 8264884  7
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB => 8670334  1  
Thu Sep 19 14:50:10.422 WIB => 8264885  6
Thu Sep 19 14:46:28.464 WIB => 8446906  5
```

### DATASET

(posted a sample as full dataset is too large)

**One iteration**

```
xr_lab#show memory compare start
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_start.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare end
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_end.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare report
Thu Sep 19 14:41:08.084 WIB

PID    NAME                     MEM BEFORE    MEM AFTER  DIFFERENCE MALLOCS-NEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2550   sysdb_svr_local          7881443     7878256     -3187       87391
7582   mibd_interface           8670334     8484152     -186182     267657
```

**Second iteration**

```
xr_lab#show memory compare start
Thu Sep 19 14:43:07.946 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_start.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare end
Thu Sep 19 14:45:27.916 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_end.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare report
Thu Sep 19 14:45:42.091 WIB

PID    NAME                     MEM BEFORE    MEM AFTER  DIFFERENCE MALLOCS-NEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6777   ospf                     24294569    24283592    -10977      227389
7582   mibd_interface           8369050     8514825     145775      126259
```

Can I know why the elements are printed out of order, and the best way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and let me know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I know why the elements are printed out of order, and the best way to fix this?

The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) has the following to say:

> The awk language supplies arrays that are used for storing numbers or strings. Arrays need not be declared. They shall initially be empty, and their sizes shall change dynamically. **The subscripts, or element identifiers, are strings**, providing a **type of associative array** capability. <snip>
>
> ```
> for (variable in array)
> ```
>
> which shall iterate, assigning each index of the array to variable in an **unspecified order**.

So from this, we know that an array in awk is an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), nothing more than a key-value-pair combination. A classic example in the programming world is a binary-tree such as C++'s `std::map`. Usually, ordering needs to be imposed to traverse and search the array efficiently, however standard awk does not give us the option to define such ordering. The standard leaves the key-order a free choice for whoever implements awk. That is also why it states that `for (variable in array)` will traverse the array in an unspecified order.

GNU awk, on the other hand, allows one to define the key-order on a global level using the array-variable [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) and on a local level, using the [`asorti(source [, dest [, how ] ])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Sorting-Functions) function. The latter will store the keys of array `source` in an integer-indexed array `dest`. The latter is populated such that the order of the keys is defined by the function `how` (`dest[1] < dest[2] < dest[3] < ...` with `how` defining `<`).

If you do not want to use GNU awk features and you know you have sorted input, then you can make use of two arrays. One that keeps track of the key-order and one that keeps track of the key-values:

```
{ key_order[++c]="key"
  data["key"] = "value" }
END { for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print data[key_order[i]] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, not tested it since lack of sample of actual Input_file.

***1st solution:*** Considering that timestamps will never be same for any other lines if this is the case then simply do:

```
awk '
/show memory compare start/{
  getline
  start_time = $0;
  b[++count]=start_time
}
/show memory compare end/{
  getline
  end_time = $0;
  b[++count]=end_time

}
/mibd_interface/{
  mem_stats[start_time]=$3
  mem_stats[end_time]=$4
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf "%s => %s\n",b[i],mem_stats[b[i]]
  }
}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** OR following will consider that you may have same timestamp sometimes in logs:

```
awk '
/show memory compare start/{
  getline
  start_time = $0;
  if(!a[start_time]++){
      b[++count]=start_time
  }
}
/show memory compare end/{
  getline
  end_time = $0;
  if(!a[end_time]++){
      b[++count]=end_time
  }
}
/mibd_interface/{
  mem_stats[start_time]=$3
  mem_stats[end_time]=$4
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf "%s => %s\n",b[i],mem_stats[b[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***Tested code with Input_file:***

```
cat Input_file
xr_lab#show memory compare start
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_start.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare end
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_end.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare report
Thu Sep 19 14:41:08.084 WIB

PID    NAME                     MEM BEFORE    MEM AFTER  DIFFERENCE MALLOCS-NEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2550   sysdb_svr_local          7881443     7878256     -3187       87391
7582   mibd_interface           8670334     8484152     -186182     267657


xr_lab#show memory compare start
Thu Sep 19 14:43:07.946 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_start.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare end
Thu Sep 19 14:45:27.916 WIB   
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_end.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare report
Thu Sep 19 14:45:42.091 WIB

PID    NAME                     MEM BEFORE    MEM AFTER  DIFFERENCE MALLOCS-NEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6777   ospf                     24294569    24283592    -10977      227389
7582   mibd_interface           8369050     8514825     145775      126259
```

***Output is as follows:***

```
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB    => 8670334
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB    => 8484152
Thu Sep 19 14:43:07.946 WIB    => 8369050
Thu Sep 19 14:45:27.916 WIB    => 8514825
```