# Can hashing of array indices be turned off?

Tags: arrays, awk, hashtable

When reading the gawk manual, I stumbled across [the following statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Intro.html#Array-Intro) (in the footnotes at the end of the page):

> The ordering will vary among awk implementations, which typically use
>   hash tables to store array elements and values.

As I understand this, the array indices (which are strings in the first place) are hashed, and those hashes are used as actual indices.

Now I am concerned about *hash collisions*. I am currently making my first noteworthy awk script which will use arrays which will be indexed by long strings (up to 2048 characters). I am not an expert regarding hashes or cryptography, but I am seeing chances for hash collisions here, and since this "application" is critical, I'll have to prevent this by all means.

Hence the question: Can we turn off array index hashing in awk (specifically, gawk)? I'd happily accept the performance penalty (if any).

Comment: as far as I know, gawk will handle hash collisions, otherwise they would have chosen an implementation to avoid that or at least mention it in the docs

Comment: Thank you very much. But the goal of hashing is to throw away the original value once the hash has been built. Provided that the original value isn't available any more, how could a collision with its hash be detected? Or do they store the hash AND the original index (hidden) in the array?

Comment: I do not know implementation details, but I feel confident in saying that implementing hashes with workarounds for collision is already been solved in many different ways.. so I don't think gawk will have any issues

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think hash collisions should occur cuz its already handled in awk itself. But I am interested in this question because this may help traversing array in sorted order(not really sure). Like while traversing an array, there is no order and disabling hash "may" result in sorted printing.

Comment: Btw, a general way of handling collisions in hash tables is making a linked list at the end of every hash result. So for a particular hash has a linked list at the end having all keys with that hash. But to know what `awk` does, need to view the source code

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution has an overview of many common ways to deal with hash collisions.

Comment: @Mihir there's a gawk specific way to control the order of iterating through the elements of arrays: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Comment: @Shawn, thanks, didn't knew about that. Would surely help when using `gawk` at least. Same for `BSD awk` still remains a mystery to me.

Comment: This is very closely related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497034/

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for the hint and +1. Closely related, admitted, but I am not sure if the answer to that question is also the answer to mine. What do you think? Does setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to any other value than the default one disable hashing, or are the indices then still hashed (meaning that there could still be hash collisions)?

Comment: Personally, I do not believe there will be a problem with awk. However, for what you describe, I do not believe that awk will be the right tool for the job. You might be more interested in a Python solution here. Also, you should not think too much about the underlaying mechanics of the language.

Comment: Hash collisions are handled correctly internally by the software and there is no way of telling awk to use some other implementation for it's arrays - they ARE hash tables. PROCINFO["soprted_in"] affects the order in which array elements are visited during a `for ... in` loop, it does not affect the implementation/storage of the arrays. idk why @kvantour said he doesn't believe awk would be the right tool for the job, I don't see anything in your question to make me think that.

Comment: @kvantour The consensus here is that awk handles hash collisions correctly, i.e. it takes care that accessing two array elements by two different keys (indices) does not access the same array element even if the keys have the same hash, so I won't continue thinking about them :-) My solution is nearly ready, and I think that awk was the right tool in this case; it can do much more things than I expected. I am quite surprised ...

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you very much! It was also my impression that `PROCINFO["soprted_in"]` on its own wouldn't solve the hash collision problem. So my question probably isn't a duplicate, at least it doesn't duplicate the question @kvantour linked.